# How can I implement bottom javascript to be working in combination with PHP and HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created quiz, it works. Quiz has radio buttons. Radio buttons storaged values (storage values in local storage). If user presses submit button these values are sent to database (it works!). When information arrived to database, page is refreshed. Page comes in, radio buttons have still selected checkboxes and that the case is. Radio buttons should lose their checked status after submitting data to database. I expect clear form after press submit button. I want radio buttons to lose their checked status after submitting.

My solution: if submit button is clicked by user, PHP script sends some information to button which is already in HTML page (main page). If PHP information is correct (onclick="" will contain "true"), javascript will start. If PHP information is false (onclick="" will contain "false"), nothing will happen.

All I want is modify somehow javascript code to be running and delete selected radio buttons checkboxes when PHP script sends correct value (true) to HTML!

I don't know how to implement bottom JAVASCRIPT.

JAVASCRIPT:

It's clear function. I don't know how modife it to be launch when $onclick = "true";

```
function clearStorage(){

localStorage.removeItem('q1');
localStorage.removeItem('q2');
localStorage.removeItem('q3');
localStorage.removeItem('q4');
localStorage.removeItem('q5');
}
```

PHP:

```
 if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $q1_error == '' and $q2_error == '' and $q3_error == '' and $q4_error == '' and $q5_error == ''){
    $query = "INSERT INTO `questions` (`name`,`email`,`q1`,`q2`,`q3`,`q4`,`q5`) VALUES ('$name','$email','$q1','$q2','$q3','$q4','$q5')";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
  }

    if($query_run)
    {
      $onclick = "true";
      $success = "Sent!";
      $name = $email = $q1 = $q2 = $q3 = $q4 = $q5 = "";
    }
    else
    {
      $onclick = "false";
      $denied = "Something went wrong!";
    }
```

HTML(main page):

```
            <h3>5. JavaScript is a/an ________ language.</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" id="q5a">a. compiled <br> 
            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="b" id="q5b">b. interpreted<br>

            <p class="error"><?= $q5_error ?></p>

            <br><br>
            <button type="submit" name="insert" value="Submit" onclick="<?= $onclick; ?>">Submit</button>
```

To save radio buttons value I use this script:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("q5");
  var val = localStorage.getItem('q5');
  for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++){
    if(radios[i].value == val){
      radios[i].checked = true;
    }
  }
  $('input[name="q5"]').on('change', function(){
    localStorage.setItem('q5', $(this).val());

  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you need to edit your question to explain exactly what is going on here. I can't even see what is supposed to happen when the onclick is activated. Is there some more javascript somewhere? Think how you would explain what's going on to a coworker who had offered to help you, and edit the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've just finished editing.

Comment: so your submit button submits the form, and you want to know how to combine that with clearing the local storage ?

Comment: Yeah, you're right!

Comment: Can anybody help me?